# I need to update grpc proto files in multiple repositories

Tags: bash, sed, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a grpc server where I change the proto file.
I want to edit a proto file on the client from a makefile.

`server` project - source
`client` project - destination

I wrote this instruction.

```
.PHONY: update-proto
update-proto: 
    @echo Updating proto
    git archive --remote=ssh://git@example.com:7999/projects/server.git HEAD src/protocol/server.proto | tar -xO > ./pkg/entity/client.proto
```

But I have problems with the line `option go_package =`  in the proto file.

the server file may have it like this `option go_package = "./;serverproto";`
the client can be like this `option go_package = "./;clientproto";`

and I need this line not to change. It remained the same `option go_package = "./;clientproto";`
and the new one should not be inserted `option go_package = "./;serverproto";`

intuition suggests that you need to use `sed`

Comment: I can name the server and client packages the same and it will be a solution, but I would like to do it right

Comment: Using `;{package]` with `option go_package = "{something};{package}";` is discouraged. If you can reconsider your implementation, it may save you further pain. It is a better practice to maintain a single source-of-truth for protos using e.g. GitHub repo names, you can then synchronize the Golang module name with the repo name. The stub code generated by `protoc` is shared between the gRPC client and gRPC server and copying either the protos or the generated code (in which you change package names) breaks this symmetry and introduces the possibility of drift between copies.